# ¿Por qué Github pages no me incluye el archivo index.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vscode, github, gitignore

Estuve desarrollando una app de clima que funcionaba perfectamente. El problema es que en el código se mostraba una key personal que es la que proporciona OpenWeatherMap. Para que no estuviera visible puse la key en otro archivo js y use un import para usar la variable. Cuando ejecuto el código con liveserver de visual studio funciona excelente pero por algún motivo Github pages ni siquiera lo incluye. ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi repositorio es: https://github.com/Alvaro0096/ApiClima

Answer (score 2):

El archivo que estas importando `keyAPI.js` no esta en el repositorio de github.
Si quieres proteger tu key personal, podrías subir al repositorio una key gratuita como ejemplo.